Streamlit App Processes Only the First PDF File When Extracting Data
I'm building a Streamlit app that extracts financial data from multiple uploaded annual report PDFs and outputs the results in a single Excel file. The app is supposed to:

Extract the company_code and FY (financial year) from the uploaded file names (e.g., NASDAQ_AAPL_2023 for Apple Inc., FY 2023).
Parse each PDF sequentially: extract text, split into manageable chunks, generate embeddings, and retrieve financial information using a model.
Append the extracted information for each PDF to a cumulative DataFrame (final_df).
Generate a single Excel file containing the combined results for all processed PDFs.

However, the app only processes the first uploaded PDF, and data for subsequent PDFs is not included in the final Excel file.

Code Workflow
File Name Format:
Each uploaded file is named in the format: NASDAQ_<COMPANY_CODE>_<FY>.pdf. The company_code and FY are extracted directly from the file name using a regular expression.
Key Workflow Steps:

Upload PDFs: Users can upload multiple PDF files via st.file_uploader.
Process PDFs Sequentially:

Extract the company_code and FY from the file name.
Parse the PDF to extract financial data (e.g., business_segment, currency, revenue).
Append the extracted data to a cumulative DataFrame (final_df).


Generate Excel File: Combine all extracted data into a single Excel file with columns:

company_code, business_segment, currency, revenue, FY.




Problem
The app only processes the first PDF and appends its data to final_df. Data from subsequent PDFs is ignored, even though the code loops through all uploaded PDFs.

I have included some the critical sections of my code:
Extracting company_code and FY
def extract_company_code_and_fy(file_name):
    match = re.match(r"NASDAQ_([A-Z]+)_(\d{4})", file_name)
    if match:
        return match.group(1), match.group(2)
    return None, None

Processing Each PDF
def process_pdf_and_extract_data(user_question, text_chunks):
    embeddings = GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(model="models/embedding-001")
    vector_store = FAISS.from_texts(text_chunks, embedding=embeddings)
    docs = vector_store.similarity_search(user_question)
    chain = get_conversational_chain()
    response = chain({"input_documents": docs}, return_only_outputs=True)
    del vector_store  # Clear memory
    gc.collect()
    return response["output_text"]

Main Function
def main():
    if "final_df" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state["final_df"] = pd.DataFrame(columns=["company_code", "business_segment", "currency", "revenue", "FY"])

    pdf_docs = st.file_uploader("Upload your Annual Reports (PDF Files)", accept_multiple_files=True)
    if st.button("Submit & Process"):
        if pdf_docs:
            for pdf in pdf_docs:
                file_name = os.path.basename(pdf.name)
                company_code, fy = extract_company_code_and_fy(file_name)
                if not company_code or not fy:
                    st.error(f"Invalid file name format: {file_name}. Skipping...")
                    continue

                raw_text = get_pdf_text(pdf)
                text_chunks = get_text_chunks(raw_text)
                extracted_data = process_pdf_and_extract_data("Extract business segments and financial data.", text_chunks)
                if extracted_data:
                    rows = []
                    for line in extracted_data.split("\n"):
                        if "|" in line and not line.strip().startswith(("business_segment", "currency", "revenue", "---")):
                            parsed_row = line.split("|")[1:-1]
                            if len(parsed_row) == 3:
                                rows.append([field.strip() for field in parsed_row])

                    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["business_segment", "currency", "revenue"])
                    temp_df["company_code"] = company_code
                    temp_df["FY"] = fy
                    temp_df = temp_df[["company_code", "business_segment", "currency", "revenue", "FY"]]

                    st.session_state["final_df"] = pd.concat([st.session_state["final_df"], temp_df], ignore_index=True)
        else:
            st.error("Please upload at least one PDF file.")



The app correctly processes the first PDF and appends its data to final_df.
However, subsequent PDFs are ignored, and their data is not added to final_df.
I’ve tried using st.session_state["final_df"] to persist the DataFrame across iterations, but the issue persists.


Expected Output
A single Excel file containing combined results for all PDFs, like this:



company_code
business_segment
currency
revenue
FY




AAPL
Products
USD
298085.00
2023


AAPL
Services
USD
85200.00
2023


MSFT
Intelligent Cloud
USD
87907.00
2023


MSFT
More Personal Computing
USD
54734.00
2023




Actual Output
The Excel file contains data only for the first PDF. Data for subsequent PDFs is missing.


Ensuring final_df is Persistent:

Used st.session_state["final_df"] to persist the DataFrame.
Confirmed that final_df is initialized only once.


Debugging Data Extraction:

Verified that data is extracted correctly for the first PDF.
Added logging to confirm that the loop iterates over all PDFs.


Memory Management:

Cleared temporary variables (text_chunks, extracted_data) after processing each PDF.
Used gc.collect() to free memory.




Question
Why is my Streamlit app only processing the first PDF and skipping the rest? How can I ensure that data from all PDFs is appended to final_df and included in the final Excel file?


It seems your Streamlit app is encountering an issue where it's only processing the first PDF file and skipping the rest. This could be due to several reasons:

Incorrect File Path: Ensure that the file path you're providing to the pd.read_pdf() function is accurate and points to the correct directory containing the PDF files.

Loop Termination: If you're using a loop to iterate over multiple PDF files, the loop might be terminated prematurely due to an error or incorrect condition.

Dataframe Appending: The way you're appending data to the final_df might be causing issues. Ensure that the dataframes being appended have compatible structures.


Troubleshooting Steps:

Print File Paths - Add a print statement inside the loop to verify that the correct file paths are being processed.

Check Dataframe Structure - Before appending, ensure that the data frames have the same columns and data types.

Handle Errors - Use a try-except block to catch potential exceptions during PDF reading or appending.


